# РасслаблеННы или расслаблеНы?

Tags: орфография, нн

*Вы расслабле**н**ы... спокойны... счастливы...*

Перед этой фразой учащимся (в рамках релаксационной паузы) говорят:
*"Расслабьте руки... ноги... шею..."*

Есть ещё предложение: *"Представьте, что вы расслабле**нн**ы... спокойны..."*

Мне думается, что в обоих случаях нужно писать НН, что это краткое прилагательное от *расслабленный*, а не причастие. Подскажите, знатоки!

Comment: Александр, я посмотрела ваш давний вопрос, и мне стало интересно: вы определились со своим мнением? Н или НН будете писать? По дискуссии я этого не поняла, а ответ вы не приняли. (А  новый вопрос про Н и НН оказался неинтересным, в отличие от вашего.)

Comment: @Sharon  Да, конечно, определился - Н. Каждый ответ по своему ценен, я всем отдал по голосу (и вообще все ответы на свои вопросы, за некоторым исключением, отмечаю стрелкой вверх). Ваш ответ и ответ Людмилы совершенно разные, они не могут конкурировать, а ответ olledd и особенно его комментарии дали мне почву для того, чтобы не просто увидеть готовый ответ, а...

Comment: А что на вас повлияло, так что вы изменили свое мнение.  Мне бы хотелось услышать очень краткий ответ, почему там пишется одна буква Н, а то я в таких дискуссиях плохо ориентируюсь. Пожалуйста, ответьте, когда будет свободное время, это не срочно. И еще: что за стихи у вас на странице, кто автор? Если не секрет, конечно.

Comment: Освежил в памяти. Одна Н,  т. к. краткое причастие. Даже если и прилагательное, то признак по действию сохраняется; глагол сов. вида и наличие приставки. Нацкорпус подтвержает - примеров с НН нет. Ответ и комментарии Людмилы по существу. Я бы его принял, вы не против?

Comment: Стихотворение (из пяти четверостиший) моё и Она (род. падеж :)) Давно это было. Попросилось в свет именно сейчас.

Comment: Тему Н и НН я понимаю сосем по-другому, поэтому мне любопытно каждое слово в вашем ответе. Так что отрицательный ответ для меня тоже важен, так как я собираюсь поработать над этой темой.  Против принятия ответа Л. как  я могу возражать, если вы с ним  согласны и он помог вам сделать верный, как вы считаете, вывод. Согласен ли на это  пропавший oleedd, о котором, я признаться, сожалею?  Не знаю, у меня нет с ним телепатической связи.

Comment: Значит, стихотворение ваше. Философское…  жаль, что я его плохо понимаю. Дело в том, что я Фрейда знаю плохо, а   Сверх-Я (если это сверхсознание) трактуется по-разному. Хотя интересная, конечно, категория, многие его сейчас изучают, причем, что любопытно,   в целях практического общения с ним.

Comment: Н/НН чаще всего пишу по ощущению что ли, от каких-то заложенных в школе знаний. Тема кажется неоднозначной и наверняка дискуссионной в научных кругах. Самого Фрейда почти не читал, а вот словарь французских авторов с большими статьями по терминам очень увлек.Сейчас, увы, обстоятельно на эту тему говорить не решусь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Орфографический словарь В.В. Лопатина:

> РАССЛАБЛЕННЫЙ; кр. ф. —ен, —ена

http://www.dict.t-mm.ru/all/racclablennyij.html

Толковый словарь Ушакова :

> расслабленный РАССЛ’АБЛЕННЫЙ, расслабленная, расслабленное;
>   расслаблен, расслаблена, расслаблено. 1. прич. страд. прош. вр. от
>   расслабить. 2. только •полн. Лишенный силы, энергии, ясности мысли.
>   Расслабленный организм. Расслабленный голос. Расслабленный ум. 3. в
>   знач. сущ. расслабленный, расслабленного, •муж., и расслабленная,
>   расслабленной, •жен. (•устар. ). Человек, доведенный болезнью до
>   полного упадка физических и душевных сил. Толковый словарь русского
>   языка Ушакова

https://gufo.me/dict/ushakov/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Как видим, чаще всего это всё-таки причастие, у прилагательного несколько другое значение (лишённый силы - голос, организм) и краткой формы оно не имеет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Скажите, а Викисловарю доверять не стоит? Там написано с двумя Н и говорится о прилагательном.

Comment: И здесь есть формы краткого прилагательного: https://ru.worldwidedictionary.org/расслабленный

Comment: http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/rasslablenno/?q=532&n=122017

Comment: И в грамматическом словаре Зализняка есть такие формы: https://gufo.me/dict/zaliznyak/расслабленный

Comment: Пока писал комментарий на Ваш ответ, пришли ещё. Большое спасибо!

Comment: oleedd , по одной Вашей ссылке - наречие расслабленно, по другой чётко написано ПРИЧАСТИЕ  с -н-, а у Зализняка даются все существующие формы, в том числе устаревшие. Так что не убедили. По действующим правилам расслаблена пишется с одной -н-

Comment: Расслаблены тоже.

Comment: Вообще-то, наречия с краткими прилагательными совпадают по форме. Там сбоку написано, что формы прилагательного и причастия. Доказательство - правило Розенталя про краткую форму отглагольных прилагательных: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=60

Comment: И ещё, вот это значение лишения силы уже в некоторой степени устарело. Для многих людей оно будет неожиданностью. Для этого есть другое слово - *ослабленный*.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с вами.

Причастие — при наличии зависимых слов. А здесь говорится о качестве (**какие** вы сейчас), а не о том, что раньше совершалось действие расслабления.

Розенталь:
Разграничение страдательных причастий и образованных от них прилагательных (тем самым выбор написания *нн* или *н*) иногда производится не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому значению. Например, в предложении *Будучи раненным, солдат оставался в строю* в слове раненным пишется *нн*, несмотря на отсутствие приставки и пояснительных слов: оно сохраняет глагольное значение, указывает не на постоянный признак-качество, а на временное состояние, т. е. является причастием. **Отглагольное прилагательное не обозначает действия и отвечает на вопрос: *«какой?» («какая?», «какое?», «какие?»)*.**
http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=60

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Больше склоняюсь к НН, раньше тоже видел этот параграф Розенталя, и вроде всё понятно, но там нет именно этого слова. Как же определиться, когда высказываются противоположные мнения, и словари пишут с одной Н. А вот Викисловарь пишет с двумя - или это ненадёжный источник?

Comment: Викисловарь - надёжный источник. Он основан на других словарях (его не Википедия создаёт). Дело в том, что форма с НН очень редкая (нестандартная). Форма причастия употребляется даже **в качестве прилагательного**. Оно на слуху. Так сложилось. В Нацкорпусе нет примеров с НН, а Н употребляется даже при упражнениях: http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=расслаблены

Comment: Получается, что норма по этому слову не устоялась?  Теперь качели моих сомнений качнулись в сторону одной Н.  :)

Comment: Получается, что Н используют и в причастии, и в прилагательном (по смыслу). А форма с НН орфографически верная (потому и существует), но не прижилась. Каждое слово индивидуально :)

Comment: Если значение качества крайне велико, то протягивание буквы звучит: *Она очень расслабленна сама по себе.*

Comment: Это очень связано с наличием приставки. По Розенталю, она характерна для формы причастия (несмотря на то, что по смыслу действие не подразумевается).

Comment: А почему Вы не видите действия? Вы расслаблены - вас расслабила музыка, т.е. лишила напряжённости. Разве это не действие? А качество - бессильный, по-моему, для этого примера не подойдёт. Именно расслабляющее действие важно. Тем более, что дальше указание на ваши действия: расслабьте руки, ноги, шею, это вы своей волей должны совершить действие. Или Вы должны стать бессильным? Разница есть.

Comment: Действие есть, но оно часто уходит на второй план: *в данный момент вы расслаблены*. Не забываем, что причастие - с зависимыми словами.

Comment: Только не в краткой форме. И вообще, не собираюсь Вас больше убеждать, если  Лопатин и Ушаков  не убедили - дело хозяйское.

Comment: Лопатин и Ушаков просто не отметили малоупотребительную форму. При чём здесь краткая форма?

Comment: По Вашей ссылке: Примечание. Некоторые отглагольные прилагательные пишутся в полной форме с двумя н (нн), а в краткой — с одним н, подобно причастиям, с которыми их сближает наличие приставки и вид производящего глагола: заплаканные глаза — глаза заплаканы; заржавленные ножи — ножи заржавлены; поношенное платье — платье поношено. Наше расслаблены сюда как раз подходит, так что одна -н-.

Answer (score 1):

Когда не знаете, что выбрать, можно посмотреть в Нацкорпусе. Форма причастия явно вытеснила форму прилагательного.

1) ***Расслаблены*** — 55 примеров

Мы стали женственны и **расслаблены**, мы больше не сможем жить под суровым оком далеких гор.  [Герман Садулаев. Одна ласточка еще не делает весны // «Знамя», 2005]

Город, однако, не кажется депрессивным, люди **расслаблены**, магазины многолюдны.  [Евгения Долгинова. Девушка с косой // «Русская жизнь», 2012]

2) ***Расслабленны*** — 1 пример, и тот не на современном языке

... паче же и мышцы **расслабленны** имуща, Печалию многою уязвися о пременении жития сего, честь же и славу ни во что мняше царства своего [… [Александр Архангельский. Александр I (2000)]

Comment: Sharon, в пункте 2, наверно, нужно **нн**?

Comment: Да, Римма, спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Теперь часто обращаюсь к Нацкорпусу.

Answer (score 1):

**Прилагательное или причастие, действие или качество, Н или НН?**

Отвечаем на вопросы.

1) **РАССЛАБИТЬ**, св. 1. что. Сделать менее натянутым, менее тугим что-л. стягивающее. Р. пояс. Р. узел. Р. воротничок. // **Сделать ненапряжённым**, вялым. **Р. руки. Р. мышцы.** Р. нервную систему.

*Расслабить мышцы – расслабленные мышцы, **мышцы расслаблены**.*
Это **ПРИЧАСТИЕ**, образованное от переходного глагола совершенного вида, одна буква Н в краткой форме.

2) **РАССЛАБИТЬСЯ**,  св. 1. **Снять с себя физическое, умственное напряжение, внутреннее возбуждение.** Р. после работы, после тренировки.

*Расслабиться – вы расслабились, вы расслабленные, вы **расслаблены**.*

Формально это **ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ** (НЕ ПРИЧАСТИЕ!), так как оно образовано **от НЕПЕРЕХОДНОГО ВОЗВРАТНОГО** глагола. Но по остальным признакам это прилагательное **сближено с причастием:** оно обозначает действие, образовано от глагола совершенного вида, имеющего приставку.

3) **Поэтому  оформляется  слово как причастие** (НН в полной форме и Н в краткой форме) согласно правилу Розенталя:

Примечание. Некоторые отглагольные прилагательные пишутся в полной форме с двумя н (нн), а в краткой — с одним н, подобно причастиям, с которыми их сближает наличие приставки и вид производящего глагола: заплаканные глаза — глаза заплаканы; заржавленные ножи — ножи заржавлены; http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62

В этих примерах **производящие глаголы также непереходные**: нельзя заплакать глаза и ли заржавить железо (оно может только заржаветь), соответственно отглагольные формы являются прилагательными.

Итак: *вы спокойны, **расслаблены**…*

Правильный ответ: формально это **прилагательное**, образованное от непереходного глагола *расслабиться*, но по остальным признакам оно соответствует причастию (обозначает **действие** и образовано от глагола совершенного вида), поэтому в краткой форме пишется **одна буква Н.**

Вывод:
Таким образом, выбор Н или НН в краткой форме имеет **смысловое значение:**  одна буква Н соответствует признаку действия, а две буквы НН – качественному признаку.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!  Если вопрос вызывает столько внимания, почему за него никто не голосует?

Comment: Голосуем-голосуем! P. S. Из комментария Sharon: _Значит, стихотворение ваше. Философское… жаль, что я его плохо понимаю._ Простите, о чем (о каком вопросе) речь?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Sharon перед этим в комментариях спрашивает о стихотворении на моей странице. Спасибо, выпросил :)

Comment: Ну зачем же так — выпросил? Возможно, просто пропустила (я сейчас нечасто отвечаю-спрашиваю). Видите, еще кто-то оценил. Иногда вопросы (да и ответы тоже) очень долго ждут своего часа. Иногда так и не дожидаются.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Пожалуйста, специально для вас старалась, даже всю дискуссию прочитала. Интересно было...  Почему не голосовали за вопрос? По той же причине: ОЧЕНЬ интересно было, вот и забыли.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за классный ответ!  А по поводу госолования... Меня в какой-то момент, уже давно (и совсем не в отношении моих вопросов), стало удивлять, что отвечающие (часто, иногда — статистику не проводил) не отмечают вопрос. Если ты берешься за него, появляется возможность еще раз освежить в памяти свои знания, углубить их, открыть новые аспекты и пр., и, в конце концов, получить за это баллы.